# Get custom stock product quantity

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I use this code to retrieve product quantity by given id

```
$stockItem = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository');
$productId =  10858;
$productStock = $stockItem->get($productId);
$productStock->getData();
```

This code work and return this results

```
array (
  'item_id' => '10858',
  'product_id' => '10962',
  'stock_id' => '1',
  'qty' => '0.0000',
  'min_qty' => '0.0000',
  ...
)
```

But I need to retrieve information by stock_id = 2 instead of default stock (id: 1)
There's a way to do this, using this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productId = 1;

$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
                                    $product_qty = $StockState->getStockQty($productId);
```